# Listen for GoogleMaps Marker unselected swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I am trying to detect when a Google Maps marker has been unselected so that I can toggle the visibility of a button.

Below is my code to determine if a marker has been clicked.

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, didTapMarker marker: GMSMarker!){
   joinButton.isHidden = false
}
```

How can I determine when the marker has been unselected? I want my button only to appear when a user has clicked the marker.

This is how it was implemented in Android:

```
mMap.setOnInfoWindowCloseListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowCloseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClose(Marker marker) {

            joinButton.setClickable(false);
            joinButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution, the first method should be:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
    joinButton.isHidden = false
}
```

A marker is unselected when any other point of the map is clicked, so:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D){
  joinButton.isHidden = true
}
```